# JQGrid Custom Formatter not working for button creation

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid customer formatter for creating button but button not showing.

```
function viewLineBtn(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    alert(cellvalue +","+options+","+rowObject);
    var rowid = options.rowid;
    var button = "<button class=\"viewLineItem\" id=" + rowid + ">View Line   Item</button>"
    $('#' + rowid).die();
    $('#' + rowid).live('click', function(rowId) {
        alert("hi");
        alert(rowId);
    });
}
```

In alert method I am getting undefined for those parameter except the rowObject.
What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think that there exist some misunderstanding how jqGrid uses custom formatter. jqGrid build **the whole jqGrid body (`<tbody>`) as one string**. By default jqGrid place the cell data directly in the cell, buy using formatter one can place another string instead as the content of the cells of the column (the content of`<td>` elements). Thus the custom formatter **have to return the string**. You current `viewLineBtn` function returns `undefined`.

The next problem. jqGrid calls custom formatter **for all rows of the page**, build `<tbody>`, insert it in the grid and only after that one could make the binding to `click` event.

It's enough to bind `click` event handler on the grid (`<table>`) element and the event handler will be called on click on any internal element of the grid because of [event bubbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_bubbling). jqGrid registers already one `click` event handler. Thus you can just use `beforeSelectRow` instead of registering your own `click` handler. The second parameter of the `beforeSelectRow` callback is the [Event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) of the `click`. Thus one can use [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to get all required information. No `rowid` is required to set. Especially your current code assign *the same id value* on the button like the rowid (the `id` of the outer row).

One don't need assign any id to the button and use `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")` instead to get the rowid.

The final definition of the column with the button could be for example the following:

```
{ name: "mybutton", width: 100, sortable: false,
    resizable: false, hidedlg: true, search: false, align: "center",
    fixed: true, viewable: false,
    formatter: function () {
        return "<button class=\"viewLineItem\">View Line Item</button>";
    }
}
```

and the code of `beforeSelectRow` could be

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("button.viewLineItem")) {
        alert($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"));
        return false; // don't select the row on click on the button
    }
    return true; // select the row
}
```

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/x0j55z1m/