# JQGrid custom formatter - edit/save/cancel without formatter: 'action'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, visual-web-developer-2010

I am currently working with asp.net to develop a page where the user will interact with a jqgrid version 4.4.4. Because of the version, I cannot use formatter: 'action'.  I have a custom formatter in place which has displayed an edit/save link.

I currently have this

```
return "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='anchor usergroup_name link' onclick=\"editRow('" + rowobject.id + "')\">" + 'edit' + "</a>" +" | "
          +"<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='anchor usergroup_name link' onClick=\"saveRow('" + rowobject.id + "')\">" + 'save' + "</a>";
```

This code does add a edit/save button which has the ability to edit/save rows. However, I was looking to improve functionality by only showing one of these at a time. For example, if the user clicks edit, then save/cancel will appear and edit will disappear.

To do this, I tried giving the html links an id, but then only the first row will dissapear after doing $('id').hide().

Is there either a way to give each link a unique id, or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid 4.4.4 is more as five and half years old! It isn't supported since a long time. I guess that you get jqGrid 4.4.4 via NuGet package [jQuery.jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/). In the case, I'd recommend you uninstall the package and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) 4.15.4 instead. After that you can use `formatter: "actions"` or `template: "actions"`.

If you still want to understand how you can implement your requirements using custom formatter, then you have some alternatives. The first way would be to use your old code, but to modify the call of `editRow` (or `saveRow`)

```
return "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='anchor usergroup_name link' onclick=\"editRow('" + rowobject.id + "')\">" + 'edit' + "</a>" +" | "
      +"<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='anchor usergroup_name link' onClick=\"saveRow('" + rowobject.id + "')\">" + 'save' + "</a>";
```

to

```
return "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='anchor usergroup_name link' onclick=\"editRow.call(this,'" + rowobject.id + "')\">edit</a>"+
      "<a style='display:none' href='javascript:void(0)' class='anchor usergroup_name link' onClick=\"saveRow.call(this,'" + rowobject.id + "')\">save</a>";
```

`onclick` method will be called with `this` initialized to the DOM element of `<a>`, which the user clicked.

Inside of your global functions `editRow` and `saveRow` you can use `$(this).next().show();` or `$(this).prev().show();` to show the second link and to use `$(this).hide()` to hide the current link. The simplest code of `editRow` and `saveRow` could be the following:

```
function editRow (rowid) {
    $(this).hide()
        .next().show()
        .closest(".ui-jqgrid-btable").jqGrid("editRow", rowid);
}
function saveRow (rowid) {
    $(this).hide()
        .prev().show()
        .closest(".ui-jqgrid-btable").jqGrid("saveRow", rowid);
}
```

One more way will be **don't use** any inline `onclick` attributes at all. The click event supports [event bubbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_bubbling). It means that a click inside of any DOM element of the grid propagates the event the the tree of parents. Thus it's enough to define `click` event on the main `<table>` element of the grid. jqGrid does that already. One can use `beforeSelectRow` callback function which will be called inside of `click` event handler registered by jqGrid. The `target` property of the Event object (the second parameter of `beforeSelectRow`) will be the clicked element. Thus you can just verify whether `e.target` has the class `usergroup_name`, which you use for your links and, if it's so, do your main job: start `editRow` (or `saveRow`), hide/show the links and so on. Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601730/315935), which demonstrates the approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I ended up doing almost the exact same thing as you did,  but I created a variable to create a unique ID for each hyperlink. I like your way better!!

Comment: @Seemingepic: You are welcome! I repeat that it would be important to upgrade jqGrid independent of your choice how to implement your requirements.